# Using `ls` to show real name of file owners

Tags: linux, bash, unix, bash-scripting, awk

Unix users can have their real names listed in `/etc/passwd/`. The `finger` command can display the real names. Can `ls -l` show these real names of file owners next to the files?

If `ls` cannot do this directly, then what's the best way to pipe the output of `ls -l` through `finger` to achieve this result? Sounds like a job for `awk` - use `ls -l | finger` as a lookup table to overwrite the third column of `ls -l`.

(Related question in case the real names are not in `finger` but in a lookup table: [Lookup-table text replacement in bash](https://superuser.com/q/1368186/))

Comment: Why are you asking two separate questions? It looks like you're trying to solve one problem and you thought of two approaches. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Would it be OK if you asked about X once? and only mentioned you think Y1 or Y2 would help. Maybe the best solution is some Y3 none of us knows yet. So why the two questions?

Comment: Two questions because they are for two different settings. In one setting, the names are available in `finger` (and maybe `ls` can access that info). In the other question, the real names are in a file but not in `finger`.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) You shouldn't try that: `ls -l | awk 'BEGIN{lc=0; while((getline line<"/etc/passwd") >0){split(line,p,":"); map[p[1]]=p[5]; lc++}} {$3=map[$3]}1'` I assume that the third column of your `ls -l` command contains the user.

Comment: As mentioned above, don't parse the output of `ls` (it's for people, not machines)... additionally, `finger` isn't really designed for this at all... prefer something like `getent passwd ${USER}`. To make things worse though, I don't think that the 4th field of passwd is standardized... see [GECOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `ls` as @Cyrus mentioned in the comments. However, I suggest a simple script to do that, which you can make as an executable:

```
while read -r line
do
    user=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}'`
    name=`getent passwd "$user" | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1`
    echo $line | sed "s/$user/$name/"
done < <(ls -lh | tail -n +2)
```

The `user` variable gets the username of the owner (from the 3rd column of the ls output), `name` gets that username's real name, and then in the output of `ls` we just replace the username with the real name using `sed`.

I haven't used `finger` in my example, as parsing the `/etc/passwd` file is less error-prone and you also do not need an external tool. (`finger` isn't installed on Debian/Ubuntu by default)

Example output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 41 Aug 29 15:13 cpu.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 193 Aug 28 11:36 httpingwrap.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 3.8K Aug 14 15:36 imgconv.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 504 Oct 19 16:04 lsp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 77 Aug 28 14:24 mg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 386 Sep 14 15:02 mon-install.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Pavlin Nikolov fanatique 589 Sep 11 11:55 ping-wrapper.py
```

Note that it is not the best-looking output, as it is not aligned perfectly, but it should still work.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead) ... `ls -lh | tail -n +2` is just the beginning... You should _at least_ be using `--numeric-uid-gid` if you're going to try :-)